# mysql crash and restart takes six hours

Tags: mysql

what can I do to reduce the starting time

2022-12-06T01:38:27

2022-12-06T04:14:16 InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 9624243ms

2022-12-06T07:50:23.877930Z 0
mysql5.7.31
the start log:

```
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains information that should help you find out what is causing the crash. 
2022-12-06T01:33:51.398988Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details). 
2022-12-06T01:33:51.399118Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled 2022-12-06T01:33:51.399151Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/mysql2/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.32-log) starting as process 29449 ... 
2022-12-06T01:33:51.886174Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available 
2022-12-06T01:33:51.886196Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins 
2022-12-06T01:33:51.886199Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes 
2022-12-06T01:33:51.886202Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __sync_synchronize() is used for memory barrier 
2022-12-06T01:33:51.886205Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11 
2022-12-06T01:33:51.886208Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO 
2022-12-06T01:33:51.886497Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1 
2022-12-06T01:33:51.886612Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions 
2022-12-06T01:33:51.888298Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M 
2022-12-06T01:33:51.900187Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool 
2022-12-06T01:33:51.908559Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority(). 
2022-12-06T01:33:52.162977Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda. 
2022-12-06T01:33:52.306201Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 69879080507466 
2022-12-06T01:33:52.922120Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 69879080770444 
2022-12-06T01:33:52.922157Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally! 
2022-12-06T01:33:52.922162Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery. 
2022-12-06T01:38:25.748511Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up in total 26093901 row operations to undo 
2022-12-06T01:38:25.749995Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Trx id counter is 2856569600 
2022-12-06T01:38:25.750009Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database... InnoDB: Progress in percent: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99  
2022-12-06T01:38:27.937131Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2022-12-06T04:14:16.554205Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 9624243ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.) 
2022-12-06T07:50:23.877930Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions 
2022-12-06T07:50:23.879487Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 2856569320, 0 rows to undo 
2022-12-06T07:50:23.883068Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1" 
2022-12-06T07:50:23.883080Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables 
2022-12-06T07:50:23.883081Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 2856569320 completed 
2022-12-06T07:50:23.883099Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 2856568950, 367 rows to undo 
2022-12-06T07:50:23.892304Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ... 2022-12-06T07:50:24.027580Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB. 
2022-12-06T07:50:24.111413Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active. 2022-12-06T07:50:24.111433Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active. 
2022-12-06T07:50:24.157138Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start 
2022-12-06T07:50:24.225198Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.32 started; log sequence number 69879080770444 
2022-12-06T07:50:24.228477Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /data5/mysql-5.7.32/data/ib_buffer_pool 
2022-12-06T07:50:24.308694Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled. 
2022-12-06T07:50:24.569514Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 2856568950 completed 
2022-12-06T07:50:24.569537Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 2856565387, 99613 rows to undo InnoDB: Progress in percents: 1
2022-12-06T07:50:24.986986Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them. 
2022-12-06T07:50:24.987005Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory. 2022-12-06T07:50:25.051557Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed. 
2022-12-06T07:50:25.054680Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory. 
2022-12-06T07:50:25.089348Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306 
2022-12-06T07:50:25.090809Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is not available. 
2022-12-06T07:50:25.090830Z 0 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0'; 
2022-12-06T07:50:25.090860Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
2022-12-06T07:50:26.592567Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 221206 15:50:26  23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
2022-12-06T07:50:30.239393Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events 
2022-12-06T07:50:30.240260Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/mysql2/bin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '5.7.32-log'  socket: '/data5/mysql-5.7.32/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) 
2022-12-06T07:50:30.272949Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 2856565387 completed 
2022-12-06T07:50:30.272975Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 2856556793, 681308 rows to undo
```

the ibdata1 file is 45G, use share table space

SHOW GLOBAL STATUS : https://justpaste.it/2616y

SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES: https://justpaste.it/9z8x9

STATUS AND SHOW PROCESSLIST: https://justpaste.it/czmzi

SYSTEM INFO: https://justpaste.it/bnx9r

the log was same before restart  like this :
2022-12-06T01:33:38.617150Z 3655217 [Warning] InnoDB: Difficult to find free blocks in the buffer pool (39741 search iterations)! 39741 failed attempts to flush a page! Consider increasing the buffer pool size. It is also possible that in your Unix version fsync is very slow, or completely frozen inside the OS kernel. Then upgrading to a newer version of your operating system may help. Look at the number of fsyncs in diagnostic info below. Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0. 22570071374 OS file reads, 1275825165 OS file writes, 185161916 OS fsyncs. Starting InnoDB Monitor to print further diagnostics to the standard output.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please.  
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions for reducing starting time.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: thanks for your  reply @Wilson Hauck。SHOW GLOBAL STATUS :  [https://justpaste.it/2616y](https://justpaste.it/2616y)  SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES: [https://justpaste.it/9z8x9](https://justpaste.it/9z8x9)  STATUS AND SHOW PROCESSLIST: [https://justpaste.it/czmzi](https://justpaste.it/czmzi)  SYSTEM INFO:  [https://justpaste.it/bnx9r](https://justpaste.it/bnx9r)

Comment: the inodb_buffer_pool_size was 128M before crashed,  I change the size to 16G after restarted

Comment: The primary reason for 6 hours on the restart was the 128M innodb_buffer_pool_size documented in the error log posted.  Using 16G IBPSize will expedite recovery in the future.  That and the details of more than 26 million row operations to undo were accomplished in your 6 hours to get restarted.  We still do not know if you have any SSD or NVME devices used for your data storage.  Please post text results of  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables:  so we know your total table count on the instance.

Comment: It still took six hours to restart yesterday with 16G IBPSize. there are 416000 tables total.one of the database has 414000 tables  for backup data

Comment: Do you have SSD or NVME for data storage?

Comment: Can you provide the complete error log from yesterday's 6 hour restart?

Comment: No SSD, I have add the log in this question, and I am going to delete some backup table to reduce the amount of tables